# Rails/Heroku RESTful locale best practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, heroku

What do you consider the best practice to handle locales and internationalization in a Rails app on Heroku in a RESTful way? What is your bit of code that gateways the user according to their locale? Is a subdomain solution (`http://de.myapp.com`, `http://en.myapp.com`, …) possible without the wildcard subdomain add-on on Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything to stop you using http://de.myapp.com, http://en.myapp.com and friends on Heroku.

Rather than using wildcard domains, what you'd have to do is:

- Manually configure your DNS domain to provide 'true' DNS names for each locale.
- Add each domain manually using the (free) Custom Domain plugin.

Obviously this is a bit more work than using wildcard domains, but should be fine unless you've got a *lot* of locales to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You have different options to set the locale, e.g. you could as well go with myapp.com/en/... .
See [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) for more information. There is no need to mess with domains unless you absolutely want to :)